# Python bulit the all function by myself

Tags: python, function

```py
def all(*values):
    for value in values:
       if bool(values)==True:
           return'True'
       elif any(bool(value))  in (values)==False:
            return ('False')
print(all(0,2,3,3,2))
```

I'm a beginner and i was try to built the all function by myself because it's an assignment on me in my course i write this code and always out "True" in terminal

Answer (score 1):

One of your errors is `bool(values)` instead of `bool(value)`. You are also returning `True` (or `"True"` in your case) prematurely.

The `all` pattern would be this:

```
def all(*values):
    for value in values:
        if not value:  # any false value cuts the search short
            return False
    # only AFTER looking at - well - all, you know for sure
    return True
```

And if you want to do this by means of using `any`:

```
def all(*values):
    return not any(not v for v in values)
```

See also [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)!

Comment: thanks it's work but i can't understand why do you make the"return True" out of for loop  because i just started 10 days ago

Comment: If you leave it in the loop, the function will always return from the first loop iteration. It will basically just test the first element. Think of it this way: if you find the first false element, you already know that not all can be true. But if you see the first true element, you don't know yet that all the others will be true as well. You have to let the loop finish without seeing a false one. Only then you can return true.